# Change Configurations after War Build

Tags: grails

I have two configurations I need to change after building a prod war with grails 1.3.2.  I know the project can be setup in ways to do this externally in the first place, but that's not an option at this moment.

1) Need to change environments.production.hibernate.default_schema defined in DataSource.groovy

2) Need to change environments.production.grails.serverURL defined in Config.groovy

Is there any way to edit the war or pass overriding arguments when running the war in JBoss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change these properties in a production application with out redeployment your out of luck. Your only option is using external properties files which will require a rebuild and redeployment of the app. See the following link. http://www.comitservices.com/wp/?p=133